# Fixed amount of cards in Bootstrap 4 card deck

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

In Bootstrap 4, can I define a card deck with just two cards (or less) in a row?

Example:

1st + 2nd

3rd + 4th

5th + 6th

7th

All cards within in a row should have the same height. But every row is allowed to have a different/individual height.

I checked those two related questions, but none of them really solved my needs:

- [How to make Bootstrap 4 card deck with fixed width cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622893/how-to-make-bootstrap-4-card-deck-with-fixed-width-cards)
- [Limit number of cards per card deck in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655837/limit-number-of-cards-per-card-deck-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: As explained in the other answers and [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895106/how-to-limit-number-of-columns-of-card-deck/38955328#38955328), you're better off not using card-deck and using the grid columns.

Comment: Ohhhh. *Your* link is super. Exactly what I have been looking for. Works like a charm. No idea why I didn't find this post myself. Thanks ZimSystem!

Answer (score 3):

So, this works for me:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 h-100 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
              ...
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 h-100 mb-3">
            <div class="card">
              ...
            </div>
      </div>
      ... {repeat} ...
```

Two cards per row. All cards (within a given row) having the same height. Very nice.